# code is supposed to give segmentation fault... But its not. Why?

Tags: c

In the fallowing code the pointer ptr is referenced to a integer variable. when is say *++ptr it is showing a value instead of showing segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int *ptr;
    int a=5;
    ptr=&a;
    printf("%p\n",&a);
    printf(" %d\n",*++ptr);
}
```

Comment: Because you weren't lucky enough.

Comment: It's not supposed to do anything, that's what undefined means.

Comment: Your code exhibits Undefined Behavior which means that anything can happen.

Comment: "Segmentation fault" means the operating system's memory protection has kicked in. It's not something related to the language in any way, **and not something implemented by every operating system**. On some systems, *if you are lucky* you are just crashing the whole system (instead of e.g. subtly corrupting the data of a different process). Never, **ever**, rely on the environment to protect you from programming error.

Comment: Besides, you were already in UB land from the `void main()` on.

Answer (score 11):

Undefined behaviour is not guaranteed to cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `a` is an auto-variable, created on the stack.  Unless you are about to run out of stack, there will almost certainly be more memory available to the process at the address after `a`.

In C, `++a` will be the address contained in `a` plus the size of the object pointed to by `a`, possibly with some padding (depending on the architecture of the processor).  This will almost certainly be a valid address within your process's address space, as it will also be on the stack.  Hence no seg fault.

Try the following code and see what you get.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    int a=5;
    int not_a=-1;
    ptr=&a;
    printf("%p\n",&a);
    printf(" %d\n",*++ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

(This may not work on all architectures, or with all compilers.  It depends how the compiler handles the allocation of the auto-variables.)